# $(window).scroll combine with screen.width

Tags: jquery, scroll, screen

i have a script:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $('#header_wrapper').addClass('small');
    } 
    else {
            $('#header_wrapper').removeClass('small');
    }
     if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
            $('#header_wrapper').removeClass('small');  
    }
});
```

It's just simply add/remove class when someone will scroll down. (it's changing logo).
But i dont want to change those in smaller devices (phones/tablets etc.) so i would like to "wrap" it with:

```
if (screen.width < 960) {
    alert('Less than 960');
}
else {

    alert('More than 960');
}
```

Is there anyone who could combine those two in one ?

Comment: Just stick the top code snippet into the condition in the lower snippet. A little trial and error should solve it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `navigator.userAgent` to detect handheld device.if yes then do not bind scroll event for mobile devices:

```
if( !/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )             
{
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
         $('#header_wrapper').addClass('small');
   } 
   else {
        $('#header_wrapper').removeClass('small');
   }
   if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('#header_wrapper').removeClass('small');  
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: It's working great, I did not think about userAgent, thanks a lot Milind, have a great start of the week !

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use CSS Media Queries. If the size is lesser than ??? the class wont be used.  You can do it like this:

```
    @media (min-width: ???){
      .small {


             }
```